# GNU GRUB version2.02 not booting

Tags: boot, grub2, gnu

I have had this problem for a while with 2 different systems. I am using Ubuntu server 16.4.4 and I am using the default booter that comes with it. When I start my computer by hitting the power button it boots to bios like normal but when I load the drive that grub is on all I see is a short purple line on my screen for 1 second and then I get no signal on my monitor. My fix was when I see the purple line I hit ctrl alt del and that seems to work. is there and way I could get it just to boot to grub automatically? Also I am not using another OS my my server system.